# Documents - Public Folder Access

Tags: document

What is the significance of the "Public Folder Access" access level - "Read Only" / "Read/Write" of a documents folder. How do we control the access of users to documents or document folders? CRUD is an option, but what would be the equivalent of record level sharing in this case.

Basically, in sharing rules etc - we can choose to give - Read or Edit Access to the users to whom we are sharing the records with. I dont see a similar provision in document folders, so how is this achieved. Thanks in advance

Comment: This [help](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=creating_and_editing_folders.htm&siteLang=en_US) explains the access model: what you set for the folder affects all documents in the folder.

Comment: Thank you @KeithC . Just a query, I have to set "Public Folder Access" are R/W because I want some of my regular users to be able to edit it. Now how do I prevent other regular users from editing it? Other than document level CRUD is there any other way. Am asking so because, for identical profile users CRUDs will be similar - unless you are giving no access in profile, but selective access by permission sets?

Comment: You'll see reference in the help to "This folder is accessible only by the following users" where you have a few options including user groups to control access. But the overall mechanism is quite limited so you may not be able to achieve exactly what you want.